# Как интегрировать автотесты написанные в Intellij Idea в jenkins на сервере?

Tags: intellij-idea, maven, selenium-webdriver, junit, jenkins

У меня есть работающий автотест. Писал на Java в Intellij Idea. Использовал Maven, JUnit, Chromedriver (не знаю что это, делал по урокам на ютубе). Нужно на удаленном сервере где стоит Jenkins, запускать эти автотесты. Как это сделать? Что для этого нужно? Какие зависимости? Ютуб и гугл в помощь конечно, хотелось бы пошаговую инструкцию как сделать, или хотябы ссылки на работающие статьи ближайшие к моей теме (Intellij Idea, maven, junit, chromedriver) чтоб разобраться во всем этом.

На сервере установлена ОС на основе Linux называется Gentoo. Там нет графического интерфейса. Узнал что в таком случае можно установить xvfb.

Comment: Если Вы подробнее опишите проблемы с которыми столкнулись в процессе, то уверен Вам помогут.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответ - Условия такие чтоб заработало как у меня:
1)Тесты написаны в IDE IntelliJ Idea (maven + JUnit + Chromedriver).
2)Тесты загрузить в репозитарий на GitHub.
3)На сервере с ОС Gentoo запущен Jenkins.
4)На сервере установить maven, chromedriver (возможно не нужен), jdk
5)На сервере так же установлен xvfb - так как там нет графической оболочки
6)В Jenkins установить плагины около 30 плагинов но самые важные из них я думаю:
Xvfb plugin
GitHub plugin
Git plugin
chromedriver - этот плагин сам подставит путь при создании экземпляра (new Chromedriver)
JUnit plugin

7)Настройки Jenkins:
а) В глобальных настройках поставил глобальную переменную (это для xvfb вроде) Environment variables Список пар "ключ-значение" имя DISPLAY, значение 0:0
б)Global Tool Configuration: установить путь к JDK, Git (Эти настройки не трогал там стоит по умолчанию), указать путь к maven, указать путь к Xvfb.

Запустить дженкинс через терминал, не через сервис.

Так же в пом файле должны быть указаны последние версии зависимостей.

В настройках задачи в поле плагины Xvfb screen должно быть большой размер экрана чтобы вся страница поместилась, у меня стоит 3840x1080x16

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Проще всего Вам будет тесты залить на git, далее в jenkins создаёте новую задачу (со свободной конфигурацией) и настраиваете под себя - укажите там git, шаг сборки, время и интервал запуска (если надо), рассылку email (если надо). Сохраните результат. Не забудьте, что jenkins должен к этому времени уже дружить с maven и git, для этого на сервере установите всё необходимое. Сам я пишу тесты на python. Вот пример джоба (задачи в jenkins). [image: 1]

[image: 2]

[image: 3]

Хотя, скорее всего Вам мало чем помогут эти скрины :)
Надо понимать прицип взаимодействия: есть git репозиторий, указываем его jenkins, задаём команду - собрать с ЭТОГО репозитория вот ЭТО. Пошла сборка. И далее просто смотрим лог. Там довольно понятно буду представлены ошибки, если таковые будут.

Comment: Спасибо кое что уже ясно. Узнал что на сервере нет графического интерфейса. То есть тесты которые написаны на Chromedrivere там запускаться не смогу. Нашел информацию где написано что можно установить на сервере такую программу как  xvfb.

Comment: Да, сейчас у меня схожая ситуация, кстати. Всё верно пишут. Но т.к. нет графики, рекомендую делать скрины в процессе прохождения теста, это поможет отслеживать ситуацию. В сети много информации по поводу работы jenkins + xvfb.

Comment: А как подружить Git и Jenkins? Какой то плагин установить, у вас на скриншоте в подзаголовке "Управление исходным кодом" есть Git, у меня его нет.

Comment: Этот плагин - https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Git+Plugin и на сам сервер должен быть установлен git. Далее убедитесь, что всё встало на свои места перейдя в Global Tool Configuration Jenkins'a. Там найдёте GIT (Git installations).

Comment: Сейчас залил тесты на GitHub в репозиторий, установил все плагины для Гита, создал задачу в Jenkins, так же мне настроили сервер (установили туда, maven, jdk, chromedriver). После чего попробовал забилдить проект, выдает такую ошибку в консоле: http://prntscr.com/gsoa3o. Написано что статический импорт и аннотации не поддерживаются в  -source 1.3. Но я не могу понять что это значит(

Comment: Это не ответ на Ваш вопрос случайно? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6513479/maven-install-annotations-are-not-supported-in-source-1-3 На java тесты не писал уже очень и очень давно. Вот русскоязычный источник с той же ошибкой: http://automated-testing.info/t/compilation-failure-static-import-declarations-are-not-supported-in-source-1-3/7489

Comment: Снова спасибо, это ответ)

Comment: тут подробнее описал проблему https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/726511/%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B5-%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B2-jenkins-maven-junit-chromedriver