# Ошибка в старте тестов в Jenkins (maven + JUnit + Chromedriver)

Tags: intellij-idea, maven, selenium-webdriver, junit, jenkins

Возникает ошибка при запуске тестов в Jenkins:

```
Tests in error: 
testStart(SimpleTest): unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally
```

Условия такие:
1)Тесты написаны в IDE IntelliJ Idea (maven + JUnit + Chromedriver).
2)Тесты загружены в репозитарий на GitHub.
3)На сервере с ОС Gentoo запущен Jenkins.
4)На сервере установлены maven, chromedriver, jdk
5)На сервере так же установлен xvfb - так как там нет графической оболочки
6)В Jenkins установлены плагины около 30 плагинов но самые важные из них я думаю:
Xvfb plugin
GitHub plugin
Git plugin
chromedriver
JUnit plugin
7)Настройки Jenkins:
а) В глобальных настройках поставил глобальную переменную (это для xvfb вроде) Environment variables Список пар "ключ-значение" имя DISPLAY, значение 0:0
б)Global Tool Configuration: установлен путь к JDK, Git (Эти настройки не трогал там стоит по умолчанию), указан путь к maven, указан путь к Xvfb.

Создан item в Jenkins настройки такие:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

POM файл:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>LATEST</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Логи в дженкинсе:

```
Started by user admin
Building in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/.jenkins/workspace/1
 > git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
 > git config remote.origin.url https://github.com/Ninbous/BabyBlogGitRepository.git # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from https://github.com/Ninbous/BabyBlogGitRepository.git
 > git --version # timeout=10
 > git fetch --tags --progress https://github.com/Ninbous/BabyBlogGitRepository.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
 > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/master^{commit} # timeout=10
 > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/origin/master^{commit} # timeout=10
Checking out Revision bdeb80d76e49ef4d8e540fe2d333bcba61c5a5c6 (refs/remotes/origin/master)
Commit message: "path chromedriver4"
 > git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
 > git checkout -f bdeb80d76e49ef4d8e540fe2d333bcba61c5a5c6
 > git rev-list bdeb80d76e49ef4d8e540fe2d333bcba61c5a5c6 # timeout=10
Xvfb starting$ /usr/bin//Xvfb :0 -screen 0 1024x758x16 -fbdir /var/lib/jenkins/.jenkins/xvfb-38-7867981789630485422.fbdir
[1] $ /usr/share/maven/bin/mvn -f Test1/pom.xml test
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Test1 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.3:resources (default-resources) @ Test1 ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/1/Test1/src/main/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.3:compile (default-compile) @ Test1 ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.3:testResources (default-testResources) @ Test1 ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/1/Test1/src/test/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.3:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ Test1 ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.10:test (default-test) @ Test1 ---
[INFO] Surefire report directory: /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/1/Test1/target/surefire-reports

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running SimpleTest
Starting ChromeDriver 2.33.506092 (733a02544d189eeb751fe0d7ddca79a0ee28cce4) on port 18918
Only local connections are allowed.
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 61.341 sec <<< FAILURE!

Results :

Tests in error: 
  testStart(SimpleTest): unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally

Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1:04.097s
[INFO] Finished at: Mon Oct 09 12:55:08 CEST 2017
[INFO] Final Memory: 9M/238M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.10:test (default-test) on project Test1: There are test failures.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Please refer to /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/1/Test1/target/surefire-reports for the individual test results.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
Build step 'Invoke top-level Maven targets' marked build as failure
Xvfb stopping
Finished: FAILURE
```

сейчас при запуске теста висит такое дерево процессов.tmux

```
 \_ -bash
     \_ su jenkins
         \_ bash
             \_ java -jar /usr/share/jenkins/jenkins.war
                 \_ /usr/bin//Xvfb :0 -screen 0 1024x758x16 -fbdir /var/lib/jenkins/.jenkins/xvfb-38-7867981789630485422.fbdir
                 \_ /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/java -classpath /usr/share/maven/boot/plexus-classworlds-2.x.jar -Dclassworlds.conf=/usr/share/maven/bin/m2.conf -Dmaven.home=/usr/share/maven org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher -f Test1/pom.xml test
                     \_ /bin/sh -c cd /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/1/Test1 && /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java -jar /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/1/Test1/target/surefire/surefirebooter6396875197907605827.jar /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/1/Test1/target/surefire/surefire704956887144562330tmp /
                         \_ /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java -jar /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/1/Test1/target/surefire/surefirebooter6396875197907605827.jar /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/1/Test1/target/surefire/surefire704956887144562330tmp /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/1/Test1/target/surefir
                             \_ /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver --port=18918
                                 \_ [chromium-browse] <defunct>
```

Тут видно, браузер запускается. Но не стартует успешно. О чем нам и пищет хром драйвер в логе задачи - Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally
Дженкинс до сих пор запущен не сервисом, а процессом в консоле.

Посмотрел еще логи в сборочной директории дженкинса похоже нет доступа

```
</error>
    <system-err>Starting ChromeDriver 2.33.506092 (733a02544d189eeb751fe0d7ddca79a0ee28cce4) on port 17394
Only local connections are allowed.
</system-err> вот такая ошибка в логах, похоже нет доступа
(WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information
```

Comment: Какая версия selenium и chromedriver установлена на сервере где запускаются тесты? Попробуйте обновиться до последних версий, если это не так. Версия selenium 2.53.1 - стабильна.

Comment: Нашёл в одном из первых запросов в google [схожую проблему](http://automated-testing.info/t/unknown-error-chrome-failed-to-start-exited-abnormally-problema-s-zapuskom-brauzera-chrome-v-jenkins-ispolzuya-maven-selenide-pomogite-pozhajlujsta-sovetom/14003/20) с кучей вариантов и ссылок.

Comment: Да я по этой инструкции и делал, у меня тоже запустили через терминал но не заработало

Comment: Версия хромдрайвера 2.33 последняя, а что значит версия селениума? Я предполагал что хромдрайвер и есть селениум

Comment: @Артур версия селениума подразумевает под собой версию джарника библиотеки селениум. В pom файлы ты подключаешь какою версию селениума?

Comment: @Артур и что написано в логах? там должно быть что-то подробное написано, приложи логи в вопрос.

Comment: Версия селениума стоит LATEST, логи приложил

Comment: root@jenkins:~# chromium-browser --version
Chromium 61.0.3163.79 Built on Ubuntu , running on Ubuntu 14.04 - Версия браузера

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ошибка была из за того что в коде теста я указывал путь к хромдрайверу, и дженкинс пытался найти драйвер по этому адресу на сервере, он там есть но похоже что не нужен, потому что плагин дженкинса сам имеет свой хромдрайвер и сам подключает путь к нему для теста.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/usr/bin/chromedriver");
```

Так же после этого пошла еще одна ошибка из за вот этой строчки в коде теста:

```
driver.manage().window().maximize();
```

этот метод вызывает ошибку на сервере без монитора, видимо из за того что нет окна, хотя есть вроде бы эмулятор Xvfb с настройкой разрешения.